# News headline keyword notification?

Tags: android

I would like to make an app that notifies you when a news story is posted with certain keywords in its title, maybe have various news sites to "scan". Fairly new to programming and would like any advice or assistance, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about how to create a Service. Then learn about how to get XML RSS Feeds from user given source. Create an app to configure your service with the feeds and keywords and let the user add RSS Feeds for various news sites. Let the service parse the resulting xml to an array of headlines and compare keywords by iterating through the array. Upon match create the notification.

Comment: Thank you a ton for the help, now i have an idea of where to start. Many thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Then please consider marking the answer as correct.